# Como clonar um objeto javascript? Por cópia e não por referência?

Tags: javascript, clone

Estou precisando copiar um objeto javascript para poder manipular a cópia livremente. Porém quando tento copiar o objeto normalmente através do sinal `=`, a "cópia" é realizada por referência. Ou seja, na verdade desejo que o objeto seja "clonado".

Veja o [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/3w1a3zkn/) com o exemplo:

Answer (score 1):

Se seu objeto não possuir sub-objetos então você só precisa de um clone "raso". Se o objeto possuir sub-objetos que você também quer manipular, então você precisa de um clone "fundo".

Eu recomendaria utilizar uma biblioteca como Undercore.js ou [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) que possuem métodos utilitários para as duas formas de clonagem.

Se seu objeto apenas contiver dados de tipos primitivos (`Boolean`, `Number`, `String`, `Null`) ou outros sub-objetos ou arrays de sub-objetos também só com tipos primitivos, ou seja, seu objeto é bem simples, sem datas ou custom objects, então há um atalho meio deselegante mas que funciona: `var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(seuObjeto));`.